# Will Hibernate use configured 2nd level EhCache with this lookup for multiple Ids

Tags: hibernate, ehcache, hibernate-4.x

I am using Hibernate 4.3.11

I have configured 2nd level cache for my Song class, but not getting many hits and I wonder if its because I usually retrieve my Song Class as follows.

```
 public static List<Song> getSongsFromDatabase(Session session, List<Integer> ids)
        {
            try
            {
                List<Song> songs = session
                        .createCriteria(Song.class)
                        .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
                        .add(Restrictions.in("recNo", ids)).list();
                return songs;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
```

This is just retrieving by primary key, but do I have do it a different way for Ehcache to be used ?

I think its only working when I use the lookup one *Id* method

```
public static Song getSongFromDatabase(Session session, Integer id)
    {
        try
        {
            return (Song) session.get(Song.class, id);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's not retrieving by primary key. It's executing a query. You need a query cache for this query results to be cached. Side note: your catch blocks are really useless. They only obscure the original runtime exception thrown.

Comment: @JBNizet but recNo is the primary key, so am i just retrieving it the wrong way , i.e can i retrieve multiple records by primary key without it being considered a query or not ?

Comment: @JBNizet seems I cant do what I want until Hibernate 5 - https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/fetch-multiple-entities-id-hibernate/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends how your 2nd level cache is configured.

If an entity is annotated `@Cache`, indeed, it will get cached during a `session.get`.

For a query, you need to make it cacheable. Which means in your case to do something like this:

```
List<Song> songs = session
  .createCriteria(Song.class)
  .setCacheable(true) // here
  .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
  .add(Restrictions.in("recNo", ids)).list();
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid adding queryCache when just looking up by Id but yes I get that works. Will only one Item be added to query cache for that query, or does it add one for every different set of values for ids variable. Does the query cache just store the ids, i.e is its memory usage minimal compared to the standard cache or does it actually store the objects to be retrieved ?

Comment: I'm not sure. I think if the entities are cached as well, that the query will cache the list of ids and then resolve them in the entity cache. But please do test it. BTW, why are you doing a distinct since the select is on IDs? It will be distinct anyway.

Comment: Good point I dont know why Im doing that (I guess i was just trying make sure) !